# Does the survival function decrease faster than linear?

Tags: statistics

I was studying about the mean residual life and theres a point where in evaluating an integral for the expression of the mrl you get (t-u)S(t) when t tends to infinite. How do we know for sure that goes to 0?

Answer (score 0):

The mean residual life doesn't necessarily go to zero: $m(t) = \frac{\int_t^\infty (x-t)dF(x)}{\int_t^\infty dF(x)}$. "Survival" may be defined differently, however.

Comment: Yeah, my question was on the numerator, when you want to prove that that integral is equal to integrating the survival function from t to infinite you get a term that is (x-t)S(t) evaluated in t to inf   
How do you now that when you evaluate inf

Comment: Assuming you are asking about the scenario of an ever increasing $t$, because $\int_t^\infty dF(x)$ must be $\le 1$, it constrains things a bit, but I'm not sure the entire numerator integral with the $x - t$ factor as a whole needs to go to zero.